# Document is not getting deleted after mentioned expireAfterSeconds

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection `users` where in my documents, I have one key `updatedTime`.

```
{
...
...
"updatedTime": 2023-10-06T16:06:26.190+00:00

}
```

I have set ttl index using script `db.users.createIndex({"updatedTime": 1}, { expireAfterSeconds:  60})`

But the document is not getting deleted after 60 seconds.

Comment: Did you store the value as string? The TTL delete job runs only every 60 Seconds, so you will get some delay.

Comment: Nope. I am storing the value as LocalDateTime.

Comment: ```
@MongoEntity(collection = "users")
public class Users {
    ...
    ...
    ...

    private LocalDateTime createdTime;

    private LocalDateTime updatedTime;
    
}
```

Even after 1 hour, it is still getting not deleted.

Comment: There is no `LocalDateTime` type in mongodb.  Which BSON type is actually being stored?

Comment: How can I check which BSON type ?

Comment: After changing the type of the field from LocalDateTime to Date, it started working fine. ``` @MongoEntity(collection = "users") public class Users { ... ... ... private Date createdTime; private Date updatedTime; } ```